# Output of OpenCV dft function

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, dft

I am using OpenCV dft function to calculate discrete fourier transform of a vector,which is real, but it is giving last column values as 0, not expected value. Following  is my code snippet:

```
//Initialization
vector<complex<double> > vec_out;
vector<double> vec_in;

vec_in.push_back(1);
vec_in.push_back(2);
vec_in.push_back(3);
dft(vec_in,vec_out, DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
for(int i=0;i<vec_out.size();i++)
     cout<<real(vec_ out[i])<<" "<<imag(vec_out[i])<<endl;
```

```
Output:
6 0
-1.5 0.866025
0 0

Expected output:
6 0
-1.5 0.866025
-1.5 -0.866025
```

What is the problem with my code and is there any way to calculate dft without using functions?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Your code works fine for me, OpenCV 3.1 using Visual Studio 2013, I get the expected output. I had to remove the spurious space in `vec_ out` though and assume that's a typo.

Comment: @Roger I am using Opencv 2.4.9, do you think  there is a problem with the OpenCV function?

Comment: Well that's the logical conclusion, I just did a copy/paste of your code, removed the typo, compiled and ran and it's fine. Maybe the defaults for the `dft` function changed between versions? (I haven't looked) or maybe your real code is slightly different from that above. Just upgrade to OpenCV 3.1 and see what you get.